# A question regarding random variables

Tags: probability

Consider the average $Y$ of $n$ independent random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$. Does that mean $Y= \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}$ or $Y= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}}{n}$?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{The sample $\color{red}{\text{mean}}/\text{average}$  always $\color{blue}{\text{means}}$}$ $$Y = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}n$$
$\text{irrespective of the distribution.}$

Comment: mean -> sample mean

Comment: @wolfies Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Average $\implies$ the second one.